# PowerShell Exception Catching

Tags: powershell, exception

I want to get the ip of some devices. Some of them are unreachable. If PowerShell wants to get the ip of an unreachable device it terminates the whole Script. I thought about catching the exception. But i could not find anything about how to catch "Host is unknown". I don't know much about exceptions i tried this but of course it does not work:

```
` try {
    $IPClient = Test-Connection $name -Count 1
    $IPv4 = $IPClient.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString 
    } catch {
    $IPv4 = "Could not find $name"
 }`
```

If PowerShell finds an not reachable device it terminate the whole Script.
How can i catch this so my List of `$name`continues and may fill the Variable with "no device found with `$name`" or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Test-Connection` is throwing a 'non-terminating' exception, which `catch` doesn't handle.  To force it to become 'terminating' (and hence handled by `catch`), use the `-ErrorAction` parameter:

```
try 
 {
    $IPClient = Test-Connection $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
    $IPv4 = $IPClient.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString 
 } 
 catch 
 {
    $IPv4 = "Could not find $name"
 }
```

**EDIT: Testing multiple servers**

To test a list of servers, catching any that fail, one option is:

```
$names = "Server1","Server2","Server3"
$ipv4 = @{}

foreach($server in $names)
{
    try 
    {
        $ipClient = Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
        $ipv4.Add($server, $IPClient.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString)
    }
    catch 
    {
       $ipv4.Add($server, "Unreachable")
    }
 }
```

`$ipv4` is a hashtable, which you can display like this:

```
$ipv4
```

Which gives output in a table:

```
Name       Value        
----       -----        
server2    Unreachable  
Server3    10.10.10.10
server1    Unreachable
```

Access any item by name:

```
$ipv4.Server2
```

Comment: Thank you for the ErrorAction Parameter.The Script should proof  **every** name  and returns the ipv4 or `could not find $name"`. For example if `$name` has three values: `test1`, `test2` and `test3`... it should return for `test1` `127.0.0.1` for `test2` "Could not find test2" and for test3 the ip of test3 and so on. Sorry if I expressed myself vaguely.

Comment: @Uni_x.  I updated my answer with one possible way to process all the servers.